# How fix formatter spellot

Tags: yii2

asSpellaut sometime work incorrect. Is solution for setting other function under asSpellout?
Code:

```
<?=\Yii::$app->formatter->asSpellout($eur)?> EUR
```

For example in Latvian actual Yii2 spelaut 1978 as "viens tūkstoši deviņsimt septiņdesmit astoņi", but correct is "viens tūkstotis deviņi simti septiņdesmit astoņi"

Answer (score 1):

asSpellout() uses PHP intl extension.

1) Try to use [MessageFormatter](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.messageformatter.php) or NumberFormatter directly with different options:

```
MessageFormatter::formatMessage("lv_LV", "{0, spellout}",[1978]);
```

See http://intl.rmcreative.ru/site/message-formatting?locale=lv_LV "Message formatting" and "Number formatting" tabs for details.

2) You can also use translations:

```
echo \Yii::t('app', '{0, number} is spelled as {0, spellout}', [1978]);
```

3) Or you can extend Formatter class and implement your own asSpellout method:

```
// components/Formatter.php
namespace app\components;

class Formatter extends \yii\i18n\Formatter
{
    public function asSpellout ($value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And set this class as application component

```
// config/web.php
'components' => [
    ...
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\Formatter',
    ],
],
```